# Building/placing objects system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

So I am trying to make a system in unity that would make you able to build. Most tutorials on the internet make it so you place prefabs. This isn’t what I am aiming for. I am trying to make a system where, (I don’t know how to describe it that well) where when you click, it will manipulate a mesh, to extend in the direction of the normal of where the ray cast hits. I saw someone do it on YouTube (I don’t know if that was their approach, but it looks like it), but they didn’t explain it that. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MazA1SlpwTY). The point where he says something about “you would just increase vowel distances, easy right; not really” right after that he shows what I am aiming for. I have tried to code it (it didn’t take long):

```cs
public LayerMask mask;

void Update(){
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
  RaycastHit hit;
  Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 2, mask);
  // here is where I got stuck.
  }
}
```

I have tried:

- adding vertices to a mesh and then changing positions of other vertices.
- changing the world mesh.
- Duplicating a prefab and then setting its position to the point of the raycast.

Only the second I made work, and (I think) will make it laggy if you do it a lot. Are any of the listed ideas usable, and if so, how would I do it. If not, how would I? If anyone could help me achieve this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume the algorithm they are using is Marching Cubes [(It is mentioned in the video)](https://youtu.be/MazA1SlpwTY?t=110). It is a surface extraction algorithm that produces isometric shapes from adding or removing vertices to a polygonal mesh. I implemented a version of the algorithm in my game [Eira Echoes of Adventure](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1273120/Eira_Echoes_of_Adventure/) (~0:36 into the trailer showcases the terrain terraforming).

I will not go into how it works as there is already a ton of [information out there](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/). There are also a lot of other similar algorithms that take different approaches to generate meshes such as dual contouring, cubical marching squares, and EMC. There are various reasons to use one vs another, but as you just want a solution to producing a similar result, MC is a solid algorithm as your first surface extraction algorithm.

As I do not think you want to heavily read into how it works, I will provide an [Open source Unity implementation](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1273120/Eira_Echoes_of_Adventure/) of MC. As MC has gotten very popular more recently, the amount of papers, videos, open-source projects, etc. has increased drastically. If you would like a few more links I used for my implementation, I can provide them for research, but I believe the open-source project I linked has a solid implementation as well as some resources linked at the bottom of the page.

The one other part you mention is lag. Yes, large dynamic meshes can be laggy. There are many optimizations such as dynamic occlusion, chunking your meshes, no back faces to any meshes, the unity job system for mesh computation, the newer Unity render pipelines that thread rendering, etc.

To show a few other examples of surface extraction algorithms here is an implementation of [Cubical Marching Squares](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWUA_HvGGDU&ab_channel=TheCyberBrick) and here's a really cool voxel engine made by [Atomontage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jItvtnc5hLw&ab_channel=AtomontageInc.). Many argue that we are gradually moving away from polygons and are heading to voxel-based implementations. One such company is Atomontage with its incredible real-time destructible meshes. Bit of a tangent from your question, but thought I would include a few other sources to show the depth of what could be achieved.

Comment: So, as you say, marching cubes will work for adding to the terrain like I tried to explain? Also, is there an easy way of making it so when you add to the terrain, the texture looks different and set the added section to something. That didn’t make sense, so I will explain what I am using it for: I am making an adventure type game where you can place certain materials. For example: wood or stone. And I want to be able to mine that. So what my question was: can I make different parts of the terrain have certain values such as mining speed and what you recover when mining it?

Comment: Yes, you can but it heavily depends on your implementation. My implementation allowed designers to change the affected radius, the speed that the building/removing happened and allowed for differing materials to be on the same chunk. I would by no means call it easy/trivial unless you have a very firm understanding of how mesh data is computed and represented, especially in Unity. It is not necessarily a 1 day programming session. It took me about a month to implement, but that was without open-source projects and a ton of videos as guidance.

Comment: Everything you just described is possible, but it is most likely not something I can just type up as there are a ton of factors that can change depending on how you implement the core algorithm. I would look into more videos / papers / open-source projects. Unless you want to implement all of this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Also, probably the last question, what did you use to start learning about MC and what resources should I use to start learning MC?

Comment: I am not sure the resources I used will be of much help. They are rather dry thesis papers. [Resource1](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/projects/ece498/surf/lewiner.pdf), [Resouce2](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/LorensenCline.pdf), [Resource3](https://cg.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/intern/seminar/surfaceReconstruction_survey%20of%20marching%20cubes.pdf), [Resouce4](https://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS4241/Project/references/Lorensen-Cline-brief.pdf), and [Resource5](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/).

Comment: But as I mentioned, there are a lot of better resources now that help ease the information in a more digestible way. Instead of reading papers you can [watch videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3iI2l0ltbE&ab_channel=SebastianLague). I would just start watching videos about the subject and the YouTube algorithm should start recommending more videos to you.

Comment: Usually, I like to work on what I can, and is there anything I can to code to get this working before I implement MC? I just want to know, will it be easy to accomplish when I understand MC? If not, then what should I try to code for the time being?

Comment: As it all heavily relies on the implementation it is hard to say. You can look into how Unity packs its mesh data which might help you understand how you are going to need to separate the textures. You can also start off a bit simpler and try [Marching Squares](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/marching-squares/). It is a 2D implementation of Marching Cubes. It might be easier to understand at first, then move on to the 3D after.